# Cannot specify child attributes in the columnset for Retrieve

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

In attempting to merge contacts in Microsoft CRM, I am using the following code -

```c#
//c1ID and c2ID are GUIDs of duplicated contacts.

EntityReference target = new EntityReference();
target.LogicalName = Contact.EntityLogicalName;

target.Id = c2ID;

MergeRequest merge = new MergeRequest();
// SubordinateId is the GUID of the account merging.

merge.SubordinateId = c1ID;
merge.Target = target;
merge.PerformParentingChecks = true;

Contact updater = new Contact();
Contact updater2 = new Contact();

updater = (Contact)xrmSvc.ContactSet.Where(c => c.ContactId.Equals(c1ID)).First();
updater2 = (Contact)xrmSvc.ContactSet.Where(c => c.ContactId.Equals(c2ID)).First();

MergeResponse mergedR = (MergeResponse)xrmSvc.Execute(merge);
```

When I try my Execute call here,I get this error -

> Cannot specify child attributes in the columnset for Retrieve. Attribute: owneridname.

Am I not setting something correctly?

Comment: Please include the missing code in your method. The error is certainly there.

Comment: @PeterMajeed - Added more code.

Comment: What comes after the `updater`/`updater2` lines? I'd suspect they're used in the `Merge` request, since they're not used for anything else in your snippet.

Comment: @PeterMajeed - The next line is the (MergeResponse).xrmSvc.Execute(merge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I had some documentation for this, but although the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.mergerequest_members.aspx) notes that the `UpdateContent` is optional, experience proves that it is in fact necessary. In the `MergeRequest`s I've tested, I always include that property in the request, and there's [a post in the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/isv/thread/f4cef39d-f3ed-491b-9927-45cb9fd01907) for Dynamics 3.0 that suggests the same.

In fact, when I try to merge two contacts in my org *without* `UpdateContent` assigned, I actually get a `FaultException` saying the following:

> Required field 'UpdateContent' is missing

Even though the documentation says it's optional!

So I'd suggest populating the `UpdateContent` property with something as in the below and see if that works:

```c#
var merge = new MergeRequest
{
    // SubordinateId is the GUID of the account merging.

    SubordinateId = c1ID,
    Target = target,
    PerformParentingChecks = true,
    UpdateContent = new Contact()
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Having `updatecontent` does not change the issue.  In fact, I get the error on lookups entered into the `updatecontent`.  I find you have to build new entityreferences:

```
    if (match.Contains("new_mostrecentcampaign")) 
    master["new_mostrecentcampaign"] = 
        new EntityReference(match.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_mostrecentcampaign").LogicalName
                          , match.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_mostrecentcampaign").Id);
...
   Merge.UpdateContent = master
...
```

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is a pretty old question, but for those of you who have run into the same issue in 2021 and beyond, here's the reason this error happens.

**TL;DR**: Ensure the `EntityReference` values for the attributes does not specify the `Name` property.

**Explanation:**

Everything that gets added to the Entity set to `UpdateContent` will be applied to the `Target` contact. When programmatically executing a `MergeRequest` within a plugin/workflow, the attributes of the `UpdateContent` get applied (as desired).

Where this breaks down is for `EntityReference` value types (lookups). The internal Microsoft code that performs this operation tries to interpret all properties of the `EntityReference` object, including `Name`.

So when the existing values from the `SubordinateId` contact are pulled using `IOrganizationService.Retrieve` (to dynamically get the latest version), the `Name` property is automatically set for those lookup attributes (the child record). This operation is not valid, even though it's not the user code that's directly executing it.

This brings us full circle to explain the original error:

> Cannot specify child attributes in the columnset for Retrieve